# Why won't DS3231 Real Time Clock continue ticking when powered only from VBAT?

Tags: stm32, i2c, c

I've got a custom STM32 board that uses a DS3231 RTC for date/time stuff. When the board is fully powered I can communicate with the DS3231 over i2c and write and read the time/date. Once the power is removed and the RTC is reliant upon the VBAT supply, the RTC stops ticking. The RTC only continues when the supply is turned back on and then the RTC continues ticking from where it left off.

According to the [datasheet](https://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/DS3231.pdf) on p.13 the control register at address 0x0E bit 7 the oscillator is stopped when the RTC switches to VBAT. How can I change this to keep the oscillator enabled when switching to VBAT? I've tried programming the register with 0, but from what I understand, with VCC applied it is already 0 and it only changes to 1 when the power is removed. But the power is also removed to the STM32 so I can't program it. Any help clearing this up would be appreciated.

Code attached for clarity.

programming functions:

```
    /* USER CODE BEGIN PFP */
typedef struct{
    uint8_t seconds;
    uint8_t minutes;
    uint8_t hour;
    uint8_t dayofweek;
    uint8_t dayofmonth;
    uint8_t month;
    uint8_t year;
}TIME;

TIME time;

uint8_t get_status[1] = {0};

// Convert normal decimal numbers to binary coded decimal
uint8_t decToBcd(int val)
{
  return (uint8_t)( (val/10*16) + (val%10) );
}
// Convert binary coded decimal to normal decimal numbers
int bcdToDec(uint8_t val)
{
  return (int)( (val/16*10) + (val%16) );
}

/* function to set time */
//Must be done in the order defined in the datasheet
void Set_Time (uint8_t sec, uint8_t min, uint8_t hour, uint8_t dow, uint8_t dom, uint8_t month, uint8_t year)
{
    uint8_t set_time[7];
    set_time[0] = decToBcd(sec);
    set_time[1] = decToBcd(min);
    set_time[2] = decToBcd(hour);
    set_time[3] = decToBcd(dow);
    set_time[4] = decToBcd(dom);
    set_time[5] = decToBcd(month);
    set_time[6] = decToBcd(year);

    HAL_I2C_Mem_Write(&hi2c1, DS3231_ADDRESS, 0x00, 1, set_time, 7, 1000);
}

void Get_Time (void)
{
    uint8_t get_time[7];
    HAL_I2C_Mem_Read(&hi2c1, DS3231_ADDRESS, 0x00, 1, get_time, 7, 1000);
    time.seconds = bcdToDec(get_time[0]);
    time.minutes = bcdToDec(get_time[1]);
    time.hour = bcdToDec(get_time[2]);
    time.dayofweek = bcdToDec(get_time[3]);
    time.dayofmonth = bcdToDec(get_time[4]);
    time.month = bcdToDec(get_time[5]);
    time.year = bcdToDec(get_time[6]);
}

void Set_Control (void)
{
    uint8_t set_control[2];
    set_control[0] = 0b00011100;
    set_control[1] = 0;
    HAL_I2C_Mem_Write(&hi2c1, DS3231_ADDRESS, 0x0E, 1, set_control, 2, 1000);

}

uint16_t timecount = 0;
char buffer[10];
```

and the main loop:

```
int main(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 1 */

  /* USER CODE END 1 */

  /* MCU Configuration--------------------------------------------------------*/

  /* Reset of all peripherals, Initializes the Flash interface and the Systick. */
  HAL_Init();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN Init */

  /* USER CODE END Init */

  /* Configure the system clock */
  SystemClock_Config();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN SysInit */

  /* USER CODE END SysInit */

  /* Initialize all configured peripherals */
  MX_GPIO_Init();
  MX_I2C1_Init();
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 2 */
  //Set_Time(00, 38, 15, 5, 14, 1, 22);
  //To use battery power when vcc is removed, the enable oscillator conntrol bit must be permanently set to 0
  //Set_Control();

  /* USER CODE END 2 */

  /* Infinite loop */
  /* USER CODE BEGIN WHILE */
  while (1)
  {
      Get_Time();
      HAL_I2C_Mem_Read(&hi2c1, DS3231_ADDRESS, 0x0F, 1, get_status, 1, 1000);
      HAL_Delay(3000);
    /* USER CODE END WHILE */

    /* USER CODE BEGIN 3 */
  }
  /* USER CODE END 3 */
}
```

Edit: Schematic and PCB layout as requested in the comments.

[image]

PCB:
[image]

Comment: EOSC should stay at zero in battery-backed mode. What's the state of the oscillator stop flag (OSF) after the RTC comes out of battery-backed mode? Did you try clearing the OSF after setting the time?

Comment: You should call the function Set_Control during setup, remove the comment slashes //Set_Control(); change to Set_Control();

Comment: On first programming, I call Set_Time() and Set_Control(). I then comment them out and reprogram so I can watch the values change in the IDE

Comment: @JonathanS. according to the datasheet the EOSC switches to 1 in battery-backed mode to save power from the battery. So it remembers the previous state but the oscillator stops.

Comment: The RTC doesn't change the EOSC bit on its own. According to the datasheet, "When set to logic 1, the oscillator is stopped when the DS3231 switches to VBAT." On the other hand, when EOSC is 0, the oscillator continues running during battery operation. Anything else wouldn't make sense since the chip has a "Battery-Backup Input for Continuous Timekeeping" - which means it can keep counting time when on battery. (Which is its sole purpose.) So... What's the OSF bit status and what's the battery voltage, measured with an actual multimeter right at the chip?

Comment: right, looks like I misread. The battery voltage at pin 14 is 3.1V as I would expect and with the battery it retains the previous date/time and continues ticking from the time VCC was removed, once VCC is restored. If cycle the power without the battery inserted, it doesn't retain anything at all. Reading the whole 0x0F register returns 0x00, so I'm not sure if I'm reading it incorrectly or if that's actually right.

Comment: just FYI, I am reading the bit 7 correctly as when I set it to 1, I read 1 back when I cycle the power. So if it's not a power issue or an EOSC issue, I'm stumped.

Comment: You have to provide the schematics how the RTC is connected to power supplies, MCU, and other devices.

Comment: Both EOSC and OSF must be 0 for the RTC to operate properly. If EOSC is 1, it'll halt the RTC during battery operation. If EOSC is 0 and OSF is 1, there was a fault with the RTC oscillator. That means you have to set bit 7 of both register 0xE and 0xF to zero, cycle power, and check if they're still zero.

Comment: After writing the time and setting both the EOSC and OSF to 0x0 I read the two registers to after cycling the power and I get 0x0 in register 0xE and 0x1C in register 0xF. So it looks like they are both set to and stay set to 0 after the cycle being powered. So register-wise everything looks to be as expected. Weird that the time freezes until the power is applied again. I'm sure it's going to be something simple. Just to note, the battery seems to be doing something, as removing it causes all data on the RTC to be cleared as expected.